# How to use regex to find strings from string with multiple brackets?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am fetching and looping on strings which can have one brackets or multiple as shown below. I want the strings inside the last bracket.

```
strOne = "This contains (18xp) (23lo) (SerialA)"
strTwo = "This contains (jxp) (SerialB)"
strThree = "Some strings (randomA9)"
```

I tried to use below code but it only capture first:

```
regFormat = '(\([A-Z0-9]+\))'
pathReg = re.compile(regFormat)
findr = re.findall(pathReg , strOne)
print(findr)
```

**RESULT : ['(18xp)']**

Comment: If you expect 1 single match, why use `re.findall`? Use `re.search`. Are those parentheses always at the end of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a regexp signs indicating the start and the end of the line. 

Try:

```
'^.*?(\([A-Z0-9]+\))$'
```

Comment: The `^.*?` is redundant, `r'\([^()]+\)$'` should be enough.